Is it fine to omit "from" from the provided sentence?

I work 9 am to 6 pm every day.
I work from 9 am to 6 pm every day.

Both sentences seem fine to me. But Grammarly suggests we need from before "9 am." Also, I couldn't find a lot of examples in published works where the writer didn't use "from" before the start time. Is it fine to omit from from the given sentence?

Omitting commonly used words, including prepositions, where it does not affect the meaning for native speakers, or introduce ambiguity, is common in informal writing or casual speech (i.e. spoken English). 'I work nine to five' or 'a nine to five job' are common. However, the fuller version is preferable in more formal writing, and is more likely to be found in published works.

In informal conversation, we commonly leave out words. This is called
ellipsis. We can use ellipsis when the meaning is obvious without the
missing items.

Full article here (British Council Learn English

You mean: without missing the items, I'd expect.

@Lambie - I specified where it does not affect the meaning.

You didn't get the joke...

Work shifts are often referred to by the (bare) clock hours in the US:

He works 11 to 7.  [a common night shift]
She works 9 to 5.  [a common day shift for office workers]

It's as much a name for the shift as it is a time-span.

♪ My baby takes the morning train... ♪

Work like a dog, work nine five [different] song lyrics

Even in published written contexts (and more so in normal conversational contexts, I'm sure), it's now far more common not to include the preposition in such contexts...

